# How to programmatically check WiFi Debugging is enabled on Android 10 and below?

Tags: android, debugging, wifi, android-10.0

Settings.Global.getInt(this.contentResolver, "adb_wifi_enabled", 0) != 0 is not working on Android 10. The same is working on Android 11+

Answer (score 0):

This feature was added in Android 11, thus it won't work on lower API.